# How to represent the position?

Tags: vectors, applications, kinematics

this will probably sound elementary but I had to ask.

here's an example because i can't put it better.

---

say, the position is defined with $ x = 2t $ on the horizental and $ y = \frac{t^{2}}{7}$

find velocity & acceleration in magnitude and direction

now can i :

1. define a function $ S(t) $ which includes the $x$ and $y$ *somehow* ?

( i don't know how to do that )

1. say that the position is a vector defined by $ 2t $ i + $ \frac{t^{2}}{7}$ j
2. both are valid ?

knowing that i will take $ \frac{d}{dt}$ and carry on with my problem.

Comment: 1) yes, of course, that is exactly the definition of the position vector $(x\mathbf {i}+y\mathbf{j})$. 2)What do you mean by both are valid?

Comment: i meant : can i define it as  a function ? is such a thing correct ?

Comment: yes, as a *vectorial* function

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$\vec {i} $ and $\vec {j} $ are constant.

the position is
$$\vec {OM}=2t\vec {i}+\frac {t^2}{7}\vec {j} $$

by differentiation we get the velocity

$$\vec {V}(t)=\frac {d\vec {OM}}{dt}=2\vec {i}+\frac {2t}{7}\vec {j} $$
and the acceleration

$$\vec {\gamma}(t)=\frac {d^2\vec {OM}}{dt^2}=\frac {2}{7}\vec {j} $$

The magnitudes are
$$\|\vec {V}(t)\|=2\sqrt {1+\frac {t^2}{49}} $$
and
$$\|\vec {\gamma}(t)\|=\frac {2}{7} $$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vector notation that you have already derived to write the position as a function:

$$ S(t) = 2t \mathbf i + \frac{t^{2}}{7} \mathbf j .$$